# Strange padding layer output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to construct a model that looks like this.
[image: Model1]

Notice that the output shape of the padding layer is `1 * 48 * 48 * 32`. The input shape to padding layer is `1 * 48 * 48 * 16`.   Which type of padding operation does that?

My code:

```
    prelu3 = tf.keras.layers.PReLU(shared_axes = [1, 2])(add2)
    deptconv3 = tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3, strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(prelu3)
    conv4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 1, strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(deptconv3)
    maxpool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(prelu3)
    pad1 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1))(maxpool1) # This is the padding layer where problem lies.
```

This is the part of code that is trying to replicate that block. However, I get model that looks like this.
[image: Model1]

Am I missing something here or am I using the wrong layer?

Comment: each input is a [48 * 48 * 32] array right?

Comment: Yes. This graph is generated from the Tflite model using netron website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, keras maxpool2d takes in:

```
Input shape : 4D tensor with shape (batch_size, rows, cols, channels).
Output shape : (batch_size, padded_rows, padded_cols, chamels)
```

PLease have a look here [zero_padding2d](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/zero_padding2d/) layer docs in keras.

In that respect you are trying to double what is getting treated as a channel here.
Your input looks more like (batch, x, y, z) and you want to have a (batch, x, y, 2*z)
Why do you want to have a zeropadding to double your z? I would rather suggest you to use a dense layer like

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(maxpool1)
```

That would increase z shape from 16 to 32.

Edited:

I got something which can help you.

```
tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(
    padding=(0, 8), data_format="channels_first"
)(maxpool1)
```

What this does is treats your y, z as (x, y) and x as channel and pads (0, 8) around (y, z) to give (y, 32)

Demo:

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_shape = (4, 28, 28, 3)
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape[1:])
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', dilation_rate=2, input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(
    padding=(0, 8), data_format="channels_first"
)(y)
print(y.shape, x.shape)

(None, 24, 24, 16) (None, 24, 24, 32)
```

Comment: I am trying to recreate a complex model in TensorFlow. Adding a dense layer would give me my required dimensions but as you can see there are no dense layers present in the model which I am trying to recreate.

Comment: okay, so you want your 32 to be doubled using zeropadding right?

Comment: Yes. I think its a case of channel padding. But I am not able to find any examples of it. For your reference I am trying to replicate this [model](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/models/face_landmark.tflite)

Comment: Thanks will go through, Could you tell what's the input to your model and what does x, y, z symbolize in (batch, x, y, z).

Comment: Input to my model is an image of shape 1 * 192 * 192 * 3. It passes through a bunch of convolutional layers and prelu layers before coming to the part shown in image. The input to the prelu layer that is shown in the image has shape 1 * 96 * 96 * 16.

Comment: Ok in a nut shell you want to have some new channels which are all zeros?
val([48 * 48 * 16]) + zeros([48 * 48 * 16]) = [48 * 48 * 32]

Comment: Yes if that can be achieved using the padding layer in TF. As you can see my final goal is to recreate the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220289/discussion-between-sayan-dey-and-aniket-bote).